# jQuery Preload image in cache and get original image size before other functions continue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

When someone clicks on a thumbnail I want to show the real full-size image in a div. I want to know the original size by src (url) before the image is loaded because I can then prepare the div size. The other benefits are that I can let the image show slowly and also if the image is bigger than the wrapper I can set the image size to let it fit nice.

**In my opinion this are the steps:**

**step 1:** Function that load the image into the cache. The script returns if the image is loaded and returns the original sizes.

**Step 2:** After step one is done function number two starts with giving the destination div the right sizes by and also the other elements get there sizes by calculation.

**Step 3:** Its time to show the image.

```
$('#img_full_size').show('slow');
```

**For example what I tried:**

```
function load_and_original_size()
{
var image;

function onload() 
    {
    window.img_original_height = image.height;
    window.img_original_width = image.width;
    }

image = new Image();
image.src=array_img_src[index_of_clicked_thumbnail];

if (image.complete) 
    {
    onload();
    } 
    else 
    {
    image.onload = onload;
    }
}
```

This script doesn't work properly. I also tried it with the plugin imagesLoaded what I use when a element already exists. But in this case I can't find the right way to get the result I want. Who can give me the right push?

Comment: please could you explain further what *doesn't work properly* means? What kind of errors came across? why are you using global variables into the onload functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always bind to onload before setting the src. It also results in cleaner code.

```
function load_and_original_size() {
    var image;

    function onload() {
        window.img_original_height = image.height;
        window.img_original_width = image.width;
    }

    image = new Image();
    image.onload = onload;
    image.src = array_img_src[index_of_clicked_thumbnail];

}
```

---

> I want to know the original size by src (url) before the image is loaded because I can then prepare the div size.

That isn't possible without having the server give you the dimensions, you'll have to preload it and get it's width/height with the above method.